# strcpy() function is enterning into infinite loop

Tags: c, embedded, dynamic-programming

hai i am having a problem with strcpy() function. this is related to embedded c programing.

the following is a part of code used in my project. Basic idea is to copy string(name) to an array _Items whose memory is dynamically allocated

```
char *_Items[100];
unsigned char contactname[36];  

Memset(name,0,36);
Memset(_Items, 0, sizeof(_Items));

for(count=0; count<10 ; count++)
{
   _Items[count] = (char*)malloc((strlen((char*)name)+1)*sizeof(char));     

   strcpy(_Items[count], (char*)name);
}

....
...function body
....

free(_Items);
```

In the first time call of the function the code is working fine, but in the second time call call of the function strcpy() func is entering an infinite loop.

I am not able to understand what the exact problem is. Please help me out.

Comment: `name` or `contactname` ? `Memset` or `memset` ? you need a [mcve], because nothing seems too wrong here (except the `free(_Items)` that probably makes the app crash

Comment: that said, if you call `free(_Items);`, you destroy your memory program and get undefined behaviour for the rest of the run. You have to loop on each elements of `_Items` to free it instead.

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc()` is needless in C.

Comment: so is multiplying by `sizeof(char)` which is 1.

Comment: `free(_Items);` causes undefined behaviour, don't do it

Comment: The `(char*)name` is code smell. Is `name` not a character array?

Answer (score 1):

did you `malloc` anything here ?:

```
char *_Items[100];
```

*No*. So why are you calling `free(_Items);` ?

did you `malloc` anything here?:

```
for(count=0; count<10 ; count++)
{
   _Items[count] = (char*)malloc((strlen((char*)name)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

*Yes*. So why don't you call `free` for each item in the loop?

Calling `free(_Items)` tells the system to free some memory that hasn't been allocated using `malloc`, which is _undefined behaviour, and breaks the rest of the execution, can be *anywhere* (that's the "fun" of it).

Rewrite your free process:

```
// allocate
for(count=0; count<10 ; count++)
{
   _Items[count] = malloc((strlen((char*)name)+1));     
   strcpy(_Items[count], (char*)name);
}

....
...function body
....

for(count=0; count<10 ; count++)
{
   free(_Items[count]);
}
```